# Does Spring Cloud Task supports file listeners?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, spring-batch-integration

I have implemented Batch processing with Spring Batch Integration. I’ve achieved the best solutions for file listeners which is way better than scheduler (cron). Now we are migrating to Spring Cloud Task with Dataflow. My question is how can I achieve the file listeners with Spring cloud Task and Spring cloud Dataflow? How does it work? I appreciate some examples or links to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Data Flow supports launching Spring Batch applications so long as they are built using Spring Boot and utilize the `@EnableTask` annotation.

We do have a SFTP file ingest example that maybe helpful located here: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/batch/sftp-to-jdbc/

If you are looking for a simple batch/task sample:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/2.4.x/spring-cloud-task-samples/batch-job